# htaccess - redirect any URL containing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It has been asked few times, but I can't make it work for my case :S

I have problem with duplicates in Google.

I want to redirect everything that contains `item/1345` to `http://www.example.com/category/item/1345-title`

eg.

```
http://www.example.com/category1/item/1345-title1
http://www.example.com/item/1345-title2
http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/item/1345-title3
```

should redirect to `http://www.example.com/category/item/1345-title`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for are canonical urls: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Comment: The site will be replaced with a new one, so I want to do it with htaccess. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task:

```
"redirect everything that contains item/1345 
to http://www.example.com/category/item/1345-title"
```

Solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !category/item/1345-title$
RewriteRule .*item/1345.* http://www.example.com/category/item/1345-title [L,R=301]
```

I am not sure, whether you need 301 redirect. Remove it, if you don't need it.

Comment: oh wait.. I get a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error

Comment: @michalis ops, let me add a condition to avoid it

Comment: @michalis is it better now?